# Database Schema Comparison - Create Table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two .bak files one for SIT database schema and another for PROD. I compared them using SQL Compare. 
Below are two scripts for CREATE TABLE.
Could you please have a look and confirm my understanding -
the only difference between these two tables is the Identity column being auto-generated in SIT database. The clustered index that is created is effectively same in both.

SIT

```
CREATE TABLE [core].[Parameters]
(
[ParameterId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[Class] [nvarchar] (50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
)
GO
-- Constraints and Indexes

ALTER TABLE [core].[Parameters] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__Para__B45738C652593CB8] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ParameterId])
GO
```

PROD

```
CREATE TABLE [Core].[Parameters]
(
[ParameterId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Class] [nvarchar] (50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
)
GO
-- Constraints and Indexes

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Para] ON [Core].[Parameters] ([ParameterId])
GO
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are NOT identical scripts:

- The first creates a primary key on column ParameterId, meaning no two rows may contain the same value in this column
- The second creates a regular index, which would permit duplicate values.

Both are clustered, but that primary/not primary difference is critical!